# Which tables do I have to export to get to store specific products?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, sql, store-view, stores

In which table of database could I export product title and meta for a determined store?

I need to take english titles and meta for products from my store id 3 (the english store)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are all stored in the database of your store.

**Descriptions are stored in: catalog_product_entity_text**

**Titles should be stored in catalog_product_entity_varchar**

> -- get entity type for products
>
> SELECT entity_type_id FROM eav_entity_type WHERE entity_type_code =
>   'catalog_product';
>
> -- get attribute IDs SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = 'name' AND entity_type_id = [entity_type_id from
>   above query]; SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute WHERE
>   attribute_code = 'description' AND entity_type_id = [entity_type_id
>   from above query];
>
> -- get titles SELECT entity_id, VALUE FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar WHERE attribute_id = [attribute_id from
>   name query];
>
> -- get descriptions SELECT entity_id, VALUE FROM catalog_product_entity_text WHERE attribute_id = [attribute_id from
>   description query];

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply, Bhagyashree, what would be the correct procedure to export these values and import them in the existing database? Should I select special fields such as disallow foreign keys or anything you could recommend?

Comment: Its very simple to export from admin then why are you exporting from database?

Comment: Yes, I agree. I could not export in admin, it throws blank page :(

Comment: Bhagyashree, would you be able to do it for me? paid work, of course!

Comment: Okay provide me admin panel details, firstly I have to check

Comment: yes sure, what's your email?

Comment: bhagyashreesurana11@gmail.com

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59976/discussion-between-yoligrana-and-bhagyashree).